# (TSQL) Store database data on different local drive than installation drive

Tags: t-sql

I'm starting out on the path of freelance development, but am used to having my database set up for me as part of a work environment. So now I'm stuck on some basics. Right now I'm trying to create my first sandbox database.

I know I could simply write `CREATE DATABASE sandbox` and wash my hands of it, but I have much more space on my second hard drive than the drive SQL Server is installed on, and would like to store the data on the second hard drive. Is this possible? How do I specify the data location? I see that [CREATE DATABASE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-database-transact-sql) has a *filespec* option, but I don't know how to use it. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What about the documentation that you linked to do you not understand?

Comment: What was wrong with example [B. Create a database that specifies the data and transaction log files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-database-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15&tabs=sqlpool#b-create-a-database-that-specifies-the-data-and-transaction-log-files)?

Comment: I was unclear whether I needed the mdf and ldf files to exist beforehand. I was still unclear after reading the documentation linked by Larnu, but a little trial and error got me where I needed to be. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using the link provided by Larnu on my question above, I wrote the following CREATE DATABASE statement. That part that was tricking me was that the **file path** needs to already exist, but the .mdf and .ldf files must not exist.

```
CREATE DATABASE sandbox
ON
( NAME = sandboxData,
    FILENAME = 'D:\Databases\sandbox\data.mdf',
    SIZE = 10,
    MAXSIZE = 1GB,
    FILEGROWTH = 5 )
LOG ON
( NAME = sandboxLog,
    FILENAME = 'D:\Databases\sandbox\log.ldf',
    SIZE = 5MB,
    MAXSIZE = 25MB,
    FILEGROWTH = 5MB ) ;
GO
```